# On Mouse Click - C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a project and I have a function which writes a text slower:

```
public static void Slow_Writing(string text)
    {
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            ch = text[i];
            Thread.Sleep(40);
            Console.Write(ch);
        }
    }
```

When someone click on the mouse while it is writing, it stops. How can I prevent it from stoppig?

Comment: How is the function called? In which thread? Clicks with the mouse where exactly, the console window? Are you sure you're not just entering the "Quick Edit Mode" mode of cmd.exe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884406/console-application-freezes-on-mouse-click

Comment: Can anyone offer me a solution please? I don't knowwhat is Quich Edit Mode or how to disable that.